# select and remove multiple files from input type file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What i am trying to do is the following:

1. Let user select multiple images ( one by one or together).
2. preview Image as soon as user selects it.
3. Let the user deselect his selection.
4. Finally, on clicking submit button, copy only the selected images to a location.
5. For eg - open [www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com) and when posting a tweet.. choose a image.

The approach i am thinking about is :
 I can use input type=file multiple times to create array of images. And make the value null when the user deselects a particular file.
This is what i am doing :

```
for( i = 0; i < input.files.length ; i++){
        if (input.files && input.files[i]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                //append a div with an image of src = e.target.result
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }
```

What this does is.. as soon as i select multiple images it reads and shows all of them instantly.But this is a one time selection.. i want when the user selects images second time.. they should append to the previous images in the array. So that i can submit all of them. And yes.. Deseclect images from between too.

The problem i am facing is :

1. What if user inputs multiple files 2 or more times. Each new time will clear the previous input field so on submitting that single field i'll only get the latest files stored.
2. How shud i remove a image from the middle of the array when user deselects an image?

I hope you are getting my ques.
Any genius out their who can solve this problem or show a new approach?
Basically, I want something identical to upload images on tweets on twitter.

PS - Its a very genuine question and Answering it can help many people.
So better not downvote this.

Comment: Make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and/or post code snippets to better illustrate your issue!

Comment: what you had tried yet !

Comment: @urbz please dont go over my issue. If you understood what I am trying to do just suggest a way for doing it.

Comment: @jackkorbin - I understand your issue. I still want to see what you have done so far so we know what we can specifically help you with. As you stated; **"The approach I am thinking about is.."** This should be somewhat provided with your question so we can easier approach your 2 posted problems.

Comment: @urbz I think its clear now..

Answer (score 0):

Got it..
I used multiple inputs which are generated dynamically on previous input onChange function. :)